# Angular: Unable to assign variable value to href

Tags: angularjs, facebook

I am trying to make a facebook share button on an angular site, but are not able to set the href attribute dynamically.

The problem boils down to the following, assuming value="abc".

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->    
    {{value}} <!-- ""-->  
    <span ng-bind="value"></span> <!-- "abc" -->      

    <a href="http://example.com/{{value}}">link1</a> <!-- href="http://example.com" -->
    <a ng-href="http://example.com/{{value}}">link2</a> <!-- href="http://example.com" -->
    <a ng-attr-href="http://example.com/{{value}}">link3</a> <!-- href="" -->
```

I believe the cause is that *value* receives its value dynamically.

How can I get the *value* into the href attribute?

Comment: What if you try that `href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?title={{response.correct}}&u=http://example.com"` ?

Comment: In fact, I don't think the `href` attribute is the problem, because I tried in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lj7snWhU6GzZXt4PiDho?p=preview) with `ng-attr-href` and `ng-href` and with both you can use `{{...}}`